# Ctrl button "stays"

Tags: keyboard

After pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + *mouse wheel* to zoom in a web page, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> seems to get stuck (not the physical <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button).  So then when I try to scroll the web page it still zooms it.

The behaviour is Operating System related and is frustrating me immensely.
Typing doesn't work (because everything is now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + whatever I type instead of the normal typing.
This does not happen on Windows 7 64b, on the same PC, with the same hardware.

It reminds me of sticky keys option on Windows, but I don't think it's intentional, as the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> buttons don't portray the same issues.

Comment: Not sure if it is related in any way, but Ubuntu has stcky keys too (System settings > Universal access > Typing).

Comment: It seemed to be that.  The next question is, on a fresh ubuntu install why would it be on?!

Comment: @JacobVlijm: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: @ReenenLaurie: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) We're sorry but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum but a Question&Answer site: It works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer.  When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas which becomes more unlikely the more questions you put into... well, one question!  ;-) So your last comment would be [a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @Fabby thanks again, and you are right, I should change my habbit :)